# hyperlinks not working when hosted from IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, hyperlink

I have a web site that is designed in asp.net and working fine in visual studio.  However, when I host it from IIS, none of the links work.  There is nothing fancy about the links

```
                    <li><a href = "#">Links</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="page1.aspx">Page1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="page2.aspx">Page2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: could you give us more details about what happens? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Just getting a yellow screen with a runtime error telling me how to change the web.config file to create custom error pages

Comment: I suspect the problem isn't your links, try removing them and trying again.  If the page builds and you're loading the page and getting the yellow screen my guess is there's a badly formed tag in the aspx or config file.  Usually there's an error message on their - that would help

Comment: you should do what the yellow screen tells, you'll be able to see the real error then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not cause of hyperlink.
Set `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your web.config to see the full error message. Otherwise, it is hard to get why you are getting an error.

visit this link if you need to know more: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/08/12/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Show-Detailed-Error-Messages-to-Developers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i'd first set up the custom errors tag in web.config to show all the errors

if that didn't work, i'd have a look at the IIS website and see if it is set up to host the correct version of ASP.NET,

if that still didn't work, i'd check

```
control panel -> administrative tools -> event viewer -> application
```

to see the asp.net warning entry that should show the exception message.

it's unlikely to be what you've posted as that looks like ok html.

Comment: I agree - just to be clear though you want custom errors off so that you can view the errors!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `runat="server"` to your anchor tag.

like this,

```
<a runat="server" href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
```